# Euclidean functions on polynomial rings over fields

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory, euclidean-domain

I was wondering whether there were Euclidean functions on F[X] (F is a field) that aren't the standard degree one. I know that F[X] is a uniquely Euclidean domain but I don't know how to use that (if it is even relevant) to construct a different Euclidean function.

Thanks!!

Comment: You may want to define your terms precisely. There are some annoying variations in this area, e.g. you could use twice the degree rather than the degree which is typically fine but technically a different function.

Comment: Well yeh you have those types of functions. I want one (if they exist) that are essentially independent of degree (and not say doubling or adding 1 to the degree)